# navigation bar overlapping content using pure css

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to implement a `navbar` using just `html` and `css`. It works fine till it gets scaled down to mobile size. This is when the problem starts as clicking on the icon in the right-hand corner results in it extending a lot further down than just where the links end which results in it overlapping and hiding the content of the body.

I've tried to use `z-index` but that hasn't helped and other solutions I found use `jQuery` so not sure how to apply that.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link href="style.css" "text/css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="nav">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav-check">
  <div class="nav-header">
    <div class="nav-title">
      <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="nav-btn">
    <label for="nav-check">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="nav-links">
 <a href="#">LINK1</a>
<a href="#">LINK2</a>
<a href="#">LINK3</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h2>About Me</h2>
<div class="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei pro delectus pertinax. Ei est utinam delectus, nec ad debet deseruisse, eum labores adipisci adversarium ut. No vel accumsan legendos, duo numquam inermis petentium id. Ne sea veniam animal abhorreant, cu tale tritani mea. Albucius evertitur definitiones in cum. </p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ei pro delectus pertinax. Ei est utinam delectus, nec ad debet deseruisse, eum labores adipisci adversarium ut. No vel accumsan legendos, duo numquam inermis petentium id. Ne sea veniam animal abhorreant, cu tale tritani mea. Albucius evertitur definitiones in cum.</p>


</div>
<div class="responsive">
<div class="gallery">
<img src="main.jpg" alt="Picture"> 
</div>

<div class="footer">
<p><span>Copyright @ 2019</span></p>
</div>
</html>




@charset "UTF-8";

/*set background for whole page*/
html {
  background-color: #26734d; 
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}
    /*--start of nav bar--*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: 'segoe ui'; 
}

.nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #4d4d4d;
  position: relative;
}

.nav > .nav-header {
  display: inline;
}

.nav > .nav-header > .nav-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.nav > .nav-btn {

  display: none;
}

.nav > .nav-links {
  display: inline;
  float: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 10px 13px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #efefef;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav > .nav-links > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
:any-link {
color: #efefef; 
text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;

}
:any-link:active { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) }

.nav > #nav-check {
  display: none;
}


/*--end of nav bar--*/

.heading1{
color:#FFFFFF;
}

/* Style the content(body) */
.content {
 margin-top: right;
text-align:left;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 /*  background-color: #3AAFA9;*/ 
 padding: 15px 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 20px;
}
p{
   color:#FFFFFF}


/* Style the validation */
#validation{
  text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 10px;   

}

/* Style the footer */
.footer {
background-color: inherit;
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#ffffff;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;

}

/* Style the table */
.csstable {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  left: auto;
  top: auto;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}

/*style the images*/
div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;

  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Moved Content Below Header */
.content {
margin-top:50px;
}



body {
margin:0px;
}


@media (max-width:600px) {
  .nav > .nav-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 13px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label:hover,.nav  #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-btn > label {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  .nav > .nav-btn > label > span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #eee;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  .nav > .nav-links > a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:not(:checked) ~ .nav-links {
    height: 0px;
  }
  .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the problem:

```
@media (max-width: 600px)
<style>
.nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

just change it to :

```
   @media (max-width: 600px)
    <style>
    .nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
        height: auto;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Edit:

for overlapping content the content will not shift down because of your `nav` has a specific height:
from:

```
   .nav {
      height:50px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      position: relative;
    }
```

to this:

```
 .nav {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #4d4d4d;
      position: relative;
    }
```

and for your `.nav-links` class remove `position:absolute` :

```
 .nav > .nav-links {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #333;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: hi, thanks for that, it worked but when the checkbox thing on right hand side is clicked/tapped, the navbar overlaps some of the content. how i do make it so that the content section starts/shifts down after the "link 3" tab, so that the beginning of it is not covered and the whole page shifts down.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `heigth` to `auto`

```
.nav > #nav-check:checked ~ .nav-links {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxe92zvk/)